# Query to select Id if in result of another query

Tags: mysql, arrays, find-in-set

I'm trying to select Ids from a table if they were found by a query on another table (my final goal is to delete, from second table, rows with ids in the first query). Here are my attempts:

```
SELECT @MyList:=GROUP_CONCAT(Id SEPARATOR ', ') AS MyList
FROM myitems
WHERE MyString IS NULL OR MyString = '';
```

So `@MyList` contains `'41, 42, 49, 51'`

Query based on FIND_IN_SET returns only one row

```
SELECT Id
FROM myitems2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Id, @MyList) > 0;
```

Expected Result:

> 41
>   42

Returns

> 41

I get the same result if I use IN:

```
SELECT Id
FROM myitems2
WHERE Id IN (@MyList);
```

I also tryed a query based on `LOCATE`, but it returns Ids not in the set:

```
SELECT Id
FROM myitems2
WHERE LOCATE(Id, @MyList) > 0;
```

Expected Result:

> 41
>   42

Returns

> 1
>   2
>   4
>   5
>   9
>   41
>   42

How can I fix my queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIND_IN_SET doesn't works because you have spaces after commas.

Replace :

```
GROUP_CONCAT(Id SEPARATOR ', ')
```

By :

```
GROUP_CONCAT(Id SEPARATOR ',')
```

Or you can do :

```
SELECT Id
FROM myitems2
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Id, replace(@MyList, ' ', ''));
```